# Identifying the type of the current cursor in autohotkey

Tags: documentation, autohotkey

According to https://autohotkey.com/docs/Variables.htm#Cursor, 
the variable `A_Cursor` has the below values:

**A_Cursor**: AppStarting, Arrow, Cross, Help, IBeam, Icon, No,
Size, SizeAll, SizeNESW, SizeNS, SizeNWSE, SizeWE, UpArrow, Wait, Unknown.

Is there a documentation (or even an image) or reference in which I can recognize to which shape their names correspond?

For some of these names, like `Arrow` or `UpArrow` I can recognize them. But not for all.
I would like to recognize the type of my current cursor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

List of cursor types, based on AutoHotkey help:

Names/alternate names from the following sources:

- Variables and Expressions
  https://autohotkey.com/docs/Variables.htm
- Mouse Properties (Windows 7)
- `C:\Windows\Cursors` (Windows 7)
- `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Cursors` (Windows 7)

```
AppStarting [Working In Background][Wait] - pointer + hourglass
Arrow [Normal Select] - pointer (triangle + stem)
Cross [Precision Select][Crosshair] - plus sign
Help [Help Select] - pointer + question mark
IBeam [Text Select][Beam] - capital I with crossbars
Icon - (not used)
No [Unavailable] - no entry sign
Size - (not used)
SizeAll [Move] - plus sign with 4 arrowheads
SizeNESW [Diagonal Resize 1] - slash with 2 arrowheads
SizeNS [Vertical Resize] - vertical bar with 2 arrowheads
SizeNWSE [Diagonal Resize 2] - backslash with 2 arrowheads
SizeWE [Horizontal Resize] - horizontal bar with 2 arrowheads
UpArrow [Alternate Select] - vertical bar with 1 up arrowhead
Wait [Busy] - hourglass (or rotating torus)
Unknown - (various e.g. pointing hand, grabbing hand, pen)
e.g. Unknown [Handwriting][NWPen] - pen
e.g. Unknown [Hand][Link Select] - pointing hand (back of hand with extended index finger)
```

(In Windows 7: Control Panel, type Mouse in search box, click Mouse, click Pointers tab)
List from Mouse Properties, Pointers, Scheme, None (Windows 7):

```
Normal Select
Help Select
Working In Background
Busy
Precision Select
Text Select
Handwriting
Unavailable
Vertical Resize
Horizontal Resize
Diagonal Resize 1
Diagonal Resize 2
Move
Alternate Select
Link Select
e.g. of cursor types not included: grabbing hand, 'Icon', 'Size'
```

Notes:

- Slash v. backslash, a slash has the same orientation as the diagonal line in the number 7.
- I have seen 'Wait [Busy]' and 'AppStarting [Working In Background][Wait]' both referred to as 'Wait', and would say that 'Wait [Busy]' deserves the title more because of the established cursor resource 'IDC_WAIT'.
- SizeNESW, SizeNS, SizeNWSE, SizeWE, NWPen refer to compass directions.

Useful links:

- [**FunctionX**: Win32 Tutorial - Lesson 2: Introduction to Resources](http://www.functionx.com/win32/Lesson02b.htm)
- [**Microsoft**: LoadCursor function (Windows)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648391(v=vs.85).aspx)

Well, that's my cursory glance at cursors.